# onClick to open menu conflicting with useClickOutside custom hook in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a custom hook to close my nav menu with any click outside of it following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEQ9nEHYIbw&list=PLZlA0Gpn_vH-aEDXnaFNLsqiJWFpIWV03&index=5&t=119s
However it is not working and I can't understand why it's behaving differently.

I have a button with an onClick function to open the menu. I want the custom hook to close the menu on any click outside it. However when I click the menu button to open the menu, the click events are conflicting - the menu state changes to open and then the custom hook runs as well and closes it again.

I have resolved the issue by passing a ref to the button to the hook as well - but is there a better way? Why is this behaving differently to the tutorial where that isn't required?

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef, useState } from "react"
import useClickOutside from "./useClickOutside"

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const navRef = useRef()
  console.log(open)

  useClickOutside(navRef, () => {
    if (open) setOpen(false);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <div className="container">
          <h1>Logo</h1>
          <button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>{open ? "X" : "Menu"}</button>
        </div>
        <nav ref={navRef} className={open ? "" : "hide"}>
          <a href="/">Home</a>
          <a href="/about">About</a>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <h1>Main content..</h1>
      
    </div>
  );
```

```
// useClickOutside.js

import useEventListener from "./useEventListener"

export default function useClickOutside(ref, cb) {
  useEventListener(
    "click",
    (e) => {
      if (ref.current == null || ref.current.contains(e.target)) return;
      cb(e);
    },
    document
  );
}
```

```
// useEventListener.js

import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function useEventListener(eventType, callback, element = window) {
  const callbackRef = useRef(callback);

  useEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (e) => callbackRef.current(e);
    element.addEventListener(eventType, handler);

    return () => element.removeEventListener(eventType, handler);
  }, [eventType, element]);
}
```